# Why my low battery alert code didn't work?

Tags: java, android

i try make low battery alert but my code didn't work its always show `Toast` massage on all level even i set `< 30` maybe somethink missing or my code is wrong? and also `Toast` will disappear when i click on screen even i set `toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`?

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int lowLevel = intent.getIntExtra("Level", 0);

            float percentage = level/ (float) scale;
            mProgressStatus = (int)((percentage)*100);
            mViewPercentage.setText("" + mProgressStatus + "%");
            mProgressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

            if (lowLevel < 30){

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lowbattery_toast, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.low_battery));
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 10);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(layout);

                toast.show();
            }
        }
```

any idea to solve my problem?

Comment: What is the value of lowLevel when it gets to the IF ? Is it 0 ?

Comment: Change to `if (lowLevel < 30 && lowLevel > 0)`

Comment: @Raskilas i has been try it but still didn't work the `Toast` didn't show up when the level reach the set value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you are trying to make a *Low Battery Alarm*, and show a Toast when the battery level is lower than 30%.

Your progress bar should work ok, but in the documentation of the [BatteryManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_LEVEL) you can see that the constant *BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL* is equals to 'level' and no 'Level', so your code is not getting the correct value.

For getting the Toast to work, you must modify the line:

```
 int lowLevel = intent.getIntExtra("Level", 0);
```

with this one

```
 int lowLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
```

(UPDATE)

This way, the Toast will be shown every time that your battery is lower than the threshold (for instance, when it is 29, 28, 27...). To fix it, a simple way is something like this:

```
private static int previousLevel = 100;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int lowLevel = intent.getIntExtra("Level", 0);

            float percentage = level/ (float) scale;
            mProgressStatus = (int)((percentage)*100);
            mViewPercentage.setText("" + mProgressStatus + "%");
            mProgressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

            if (lowLevel < 30 && previousLevel >= 30){

                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lowbattery_toast, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.low_battery));
                Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 10);
                toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setView(layout);

                toast.show();
            }

            previousLevel = lowLevel;
        }
```

Comment: the `Toast` always show up when battery reach a certain level that has been set. exp.i set battery level to =30 when the battery reach that level the `Toast` always show up repeatly until level change under that level

Comment: @ForceGaming you should keep a variable, such as a static one or one stored in the SharedPreferences, to known if the Toast was already shown or not. You must set it to true the first time that the battery level goes below your threshold, and set it to false the first time the battery level goes above the threshold.

Comment: I edited the accepted answer to include it, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up, a broadcast receiver for the

> ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

intent is set up dynamically, because it can not be received through components declared in manifests, only by explicitly registering for it with

> Context.registerReceiver()

.

```
public class Main extends Activity { private TextView batteryTxt; private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){ @Override public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) { int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0); batteryTxt.setText(String.valueOf(level) + "%"); } }; @Override public void onCreate(Bundle b) { super.onCreate(b); setContentView(R.layout.main); batteryTxt = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.batteryTxt); this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)); } }
```